# Google Authenticator what is the best way to see the full entry line

Tags: google-authenticator

Cannot change the app name nor cannot see the full entry name.

I have 10 entries in Google Authenticator for example "Amazon Web Services". I only see "Amazon Web Services" 10 times, no way to know which one is correct. I can change *account name*, but since account name is not even visible with this long application name there is no help. Account name is the latter part of full entry line.

Only thing that I found helpfull is to put the phone Font size to smallest possible, however drawback is that its a global setting and has its obvious side effects to overall usability.

I need to count entry index and remember it by hand to be able to use correct one which is obviously not very convienent.

So two important usability features missing:

- Ability to change application name also ( not just account name )
- Abitily to wrap long lines into two rows (should be kind a basic thing in app!)

I am using very new Android 13 phone now, after transferring data to new phone authenticator even re-sorted my entries, so back to guessing game for correct entry by index

Comment: No offense, but Google Authenticator is terrible for stuff like this... Consider Authy or Bitwarden to manage your 2FA codes instead. Understand I am not against Google and the Authenticator app is fine for many things, but when you have entries like this there is no good way to manage them I have found.